# Delete from localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I am trying to use local storage for my little table where i just want to save few things here is my current code:

```
    $("#dodaj").click(function()
    {


        var str = "<tr onclick='Oznaci(this)'><td>"+stevilka+"</td><td>"+naslov+"</td><td>"+vrsta+"</td><td>"+nujnost+"</td><td>"+datum+"</td></tr>";
        $("#tabela").append(str);

        localStorage.podatki = localStorage.podatki + str;
    });

    $("#odstrani").click(function()
    {
        {
            $(".rdeca").remove();   
            localStorage.removeItem(".rdeca");      
        }
    });




function Oznaci(vrstica)
{
    $(vrstica).css({"background-color":"#FF0000"});
    $(vrstica).attr("class","rdeca");
}
```

I sucessfully add to the localStorage, but when i call `localStorage.removeItem(".rdeca");` it does not remove it. I am probably removing the wrong thing (.rdeca). As i should probably remove the string combined like str from it, but i dont know how i can manage to do thath. THanks for your help

Comment: I think you need to use `localStorage.removeItem("rdeca")`

Comment: Nope it does not work too.

Comment: Where are you setting the `.rdeca` item? I only see you setting the `podatki` item.

Comment: I mark the clicked lines in table with red color, and this lines should be removed from the `localStorage` when i click delete.

Answer (score 8):

The only assignment to `localStorage` that's shown in your code is this:

```
localStorage.podatki = localStorage.podatki + str;
```

The name of the item you stored is `podatki` so you need to remove it using that name:

```
localStorage.removeItem("podatki")
```

If your goal is to **remove just a part of the value stored under that name, then you'll need to perform that operation manually**. That is, you'll need to read the property, modify it as needed, and then write back to it.

Comment: Yes but with remove item podatki i will delete all entryes. With method Oznaci i mark all lines which i want to remove and when i click button delete it should remove it. But dont know how should i acess these.

Comment: OK, well, if your goal is to remove just a part of the value stored under that name, then you'll need to perform that operation manually.

Answer (score 1):

The item in localstorage has no jQuery methods to update it.

You need to manually pull the stuff out of localstorage, delete the node, and reinsert it.